# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

When I execute a program, I got a problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/xxxxx/SadTalker/src/facerender/animate.py", line 252, in generate
    imageio.mimsave(enhanced_path, enhanced_images_gen_with_len, fps=float(25))
  File "/data/miniconda3/envs/sadtalker_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/imageio/v2.py", line 331, in mimwrite
    return file.write(ims, **kwargs)
  File "/data/miniconda3/envs/sadtalker_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/imageio/core/legacy_plugin_wrapper.py", line 188, in write
    for written, ndimage in enumerate(ndimage):
  File "/data/xxxxx/SadTalker/src/utils/face_enhancer.py", line 113, in enhancer_generator_no_len
    img = cv2.cvtColor(images[idx], cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

I have no idea to solve it.

I changed the version of opecv, but it makes no sense.

Comment: Where do you call `cvtColor()`? Could you please also share the breakpoint in your script?

Comment: `images[idx]` is not a numpy array

Comment: Should be `img = cv2.cvtColor(images, ....)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. It seems like a bug when I debug the program.
`images[idx]` sometimes is empty. I will fix it soon.
Thank you all!